# не понимаю что поправить что бы пройти тесты, Python

Tags: python, pytest

есть тест:

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from django.test import Client, TestCase


class StaticPagesURLTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.guest_client = Client()

    def test_about_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
        """Проверка доступности страниц."""
        response = self.guest_client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)

        response = self.guest_client.get('/second_page/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)

    def test_page_shows_correct_content(self):
        """Проверка контента страниц."""
        response = self.guest_client.get('/')
        self.assertContains(response, 'У меня получилось!')

        response = self.guest_client.get('/second_page/')
        self.assertContains(response, 'А это вторая страница!')
```

Есть вьюха и урл

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    data = 'У меня получилось!'
    return HttpResponse(data, status_code=200)


def second_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('А это вторая страница', status_code=200)
```

url

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'infra_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('infra_app/second/', views.second_page, name='second_page'),

]
```

не понимаю что нужно поменять что бы пройти тест, пытался в ручную вернуть status_code=200 или HTTPStatus.OK (конечно делал from http import HTTPStatus) - всеравно тесты не проходит

Ошибка по тесту:

```
FAIL: test_about_url_exists_at_desired_location (infra_app.tests.StaticPagesURLTests)
Проверка доступности страниц.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/infra_actions/infra_actions/infra_project/infra_app/tests.py", line 16, in test_about_url_exists_at_desired_location
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
AssertionError: 404 != <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>

======================================================================
FAIL: test_page_shows_correct_content (infra_app.tests.StaticPagesURLTests)
Проверка контента страниц.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/infra_actions/infra_actions/infra_project/infra_app/tests.py", line 24, in test_page_shows_correct_content
    self.assertContains(response, 'А это вторая страница!')
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 446, in assertContains
    response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 418, in _assert_contains
    " (expected %d)" % (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: 404 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 404 (expected 200)
```

Comment: Что конкретно значит «тесты не проходит»? Какие ошибки пишет?

Comment: Но как минимум сразу видно, что тест пытается посетить ссылку `/second_page/` которая не существует

Comment: Добавил описание ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Ну да, ошибка говорит именно о том, что ссылка `/second_page/` не существует

Comment: изменил urls 

path('/second_page/', views.second_page, name='second_page'),

ошибка не ушла, ошибку перезаписал в вопрос

Comment: Похоже, вы не очень понимаете, как работает urls в django, видимо, вам стоит начать с чтения туториалов и документации

Answer (score 1):

По сути это тест на внимательность, нужно привести логику проекта в соответствии с тестами `path('second_page/', views.second_page, name='second_page')` в urls.py и `def second_page(request): return HttpResponse('А это вторая страница!')` добавить "!" во views.py